# Tests in Scala with specs2 are executed many times

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, specs2

I start in Scala with Play2, and I find out that my tests are always executed many times. here un example :

```
trait IsolationContext extends Scope {
  var value = 1
}
class TestSpec extends Specification  {

  "Specification 1" should {

    "be tested here" >> new IsolationContext {
      value += 1
      println("TEST 1 : " + value)
      value must be_>=(1)
    }

    "and also here" >> new IsolationContext{
      value += 2
      println("TEST 2 : " + value)
      value must be_>=(2)
    }
  }

  "Specification 2" should {

    "be tested here" >> new IsolationContext {
      value += 3
      println("TEST 3 : " + value)
      value must be_>=(3)
    }

    "and also here" >>  new IsolationContext {
      value += 4
      println("TEST 4 : " + value)
      value must be_>=(4)
    }
  }
}
```

When I launch test in InteliJ, here I obtain :

> ```
> TEST 1 : 2
> TEST 3 : 4
> TEST 2 : 3
> TEST 4 : 5
> TEST 1 : 2
> TEST 3 : 4
> TEST 2 : 3
> TEST 4 : 5
> TEST 1 : 2
> TEST 3 : 4
> TEST 2 : 3
> TEST 4 : 5
> TEST 1 : 2
> TEST 3 : 4
> TEST 2 : 3
> TEST 4 : 5
> ```

Each test is executed four times, sometimes two. I must specify sequential for execute tests only one times.
In Eclipse, with the annotation @RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner]), all works perfectly. So I suppose it is a problem (bug ?) with IntelliJ. Can you confirm me, or tell me where I'm wrong.

Thanks

Comment: There must be something else because everything works ok for me: specs2 2.3.10, Intellij 13.1 with the latest Scala plugin.